# Including js file in openlayer.js file

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, csv

I have this code for showing markers on map:

function addUserLayerCSV(){

```
layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("CSV", {
            projection: epsg6316,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                   url: "./../clientUploads/"+ FileURL,   
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()

            })
        }
```

and i have another js file where i convert commas in csv file into tabs, so Openlayers.Format.Text could do the job. Question is, how can i include that js file into this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run your script, convert the csv and then read the converted data with the OpenLayers.Text-format.

But I also think that it's more straightforward to change the way the csv is read if you can't change the csv (on the server side) before you read it with OpenLayers.

I just gave it a quick try and it works. I just made a copy of the file "Text.js" in the subfolder "OpenLayers/lib/OpenLayers/Format" and changed the content so it does not expect tabs anymore but commas.(make sure that you use dots as a separator for coordinates and size):
like
53.7,mein titel6,meine beschreibung6,data/img/yellow.png,15.20

here the js-Part:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/g22psc9o/

[image]

and the path:
[image]

Comment: It seems like this could do the job, but i can't find Format folder. Maybe cause of version of Openlayers, i use 2.13. Thanks for your time, u did good job :)

Comment: I also use ol 2.13 and there it is here:  ...yourpath_to_openlayers/OpenLayers-2.13.1\lib\OpenLayers\Format\  (just added a screenshot in my answer above)

Comment: ha nice @Thomas, with screenshots and all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look on the OL.Format.Text [code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Format/Text.js) (not a big class) and see if you can extend it to use your own parser? I mean, creating a new OL.Format class that has your own logic on how your data is structured, that is, basically changing some bits on the [read](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Format/Text.js#L77) method.

Comment: Well that's exactly what Thomas did. So i did it too, and it works :) Tnx anyway